How to pass the search string from the input field to the query parameters, when the binded blazor component property has changed?
How can I real-time update the request parameter in the URL when the user typing in the input text field?
Here is a simple sample of what I have:
@page "/"
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.QuickGrid

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>
<h1>Search Persons</h1>
@* <search @bind="SearchString" @bind:event="oninput"/> *@
<input type="search" name="searchString" @bind="SearchString" @bind:event="oninput">
<QuickGrid TGridItem="Person" Items="FilteredPersons">
    <PropertyColumn Property="@(p => p.PersonId)" Sortable="true"/>
    <PropertyColumn Property="@(p => p.Name)" Sortable="true"/>
    <PropertyColumn Property="@(p => p.BirthDate)" Sortable="true"/>
</QuickGrid>

@code{
    [Parameter, SupplyParameterFromQuery] public string? SearchString { get; set; }

    private IQueryable<Person> FilteredPersons =>
        _persons.Where(m => m.Name.Contains(SearchString ?? string.Empty, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

    private record Person(int PersonId, string Name, DateOnly BirthDate);

    private readonly IQueryable<Person> _persons = new[]
    {
        new Person(10895, "Jean Martin", new DateOnly(1985, 3, 16)),
        new Person(10944, "António Langa", new DateOnly(1991, 12, 1)),
        new Person(11203, "Julie Smith", new DateOnly(1958, 10, 10)),
        new Person(11205, "Nur Sari", new DateOnly(1922, 4, 27)),
        new Person(11898, "Jose Hernandez", new DateOnly(2011, 5, 3)),
        new Person(12130, "Kenji Sato", new DateOnly(2004, 1, 9)),
    }.AsQueryable();

}

As you can see, nothing changes in the URL when the user enters a value into the filter.
But in this case, it is expected to see https://localhost:44332/?search=J there.


Do you want real-time updates on the URL when the user is typing or only change the URL when the user presses ENTER?

@YongShun, I want to real-time updates

I am not sure that real-time update is a good idea because with this behavior this will refresh the page each time the input field is updated. Let me know if you are keen to this behavior.

Probably you need the onchange event & function; and in your OnChange function you need NavigationManager.NavigateTo() to redirect to the URL.

@YongShun, I don't want to refresh the page. I need the filter value to be saved in the url. This is also a typical way to save filters on store websites. This is necessary so that the user can share the link with another user.

The answer is simple. You just need to add a Callback after changing the parameter and apply the method NavigationManager.Navigate(string uri, bool forceLoad = false, bool replace = false). It is also recommended to use the bool replace = true parameter so as not to overload the browser page history with each new letter in the filter.
NavigationManager.NavigateTo does not reload the page if only the request parameters are changed and the forceLoad = false.
@page "/"
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.QuickGrid
@inject NavigationManager NavMan

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>
<h1>Search Persons</h1>
<input type="search" name="searchString" @bind="SearchString" @bind:event="oninput" @bind:after="Callback">
<QuickGrid TGridItem="Person" Items="FilteredPersons">
    <PropertyColumn Property="@(p => p.PersonId)" Sortable="true"/>
    <PropertyColumn Property="@(p => p.Name)" Sortable="true"/>
    <PropertyColumn Property="@(p => p.BirthDate)" Sortable="true"/>
</QuickGrid>

@code{
    [Parameter, SupplyParameterFromQuery] public string? SearchString { get; set; }

    private IQueryable<Person> FilteredPersons =>
        _persons.Where(m => m.Name.Contains(SearchString ?? string.Empty, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

    private record Person(int PersonId, string Name, DateOnly BirthDate);

    private readonly IQueryable<Person> _persons = new Person[]
    {
        /*Sample data*/
    }.AsQueryable();

    private void Callback()
    {
        var url = NavMan.GetUriWithQueryParameter(nameof(SearchString), SearchString);
        NavMan.NavigateTo(url);
    }
}


You can use the @bind:after event and NavigationManager.NavigateTo method to set the query parameter. Code like this:
@page "/gridlist"
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.QuickGrid
@inject NavigationManager NavMan

<h1>Search Persons</h1>
@* <search @bind="SearchString" @bind:event="oninput"/> *@
<input type="search" name="searchString" @bind="SearchString" @bind:event="oninput" @bind:after="PerformSearch"> 
<QuickGrid TGridItem="Person" Items="FilteredPersons">
    <PropertyColumn Property="@(p => p.PersonId)" Sortable="true" />
    <PropertyColumn Property="@(p => p.Name)" Sortable="true" />
    <PropertyColumn Property="@(p => p.BirthDate)" Sortable="true" />
</QuickGrid>

@code {
    [Parameter, SupplyParameterFromQuery] 
    public string? SearchString { get; set; } 
    private IQueryable<Person> FilteredPersons =>
        _persons.Where(m => m.Name.Contains(SearchString ?? string.Empty, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

    private record Person(int PersonId, string Name, DateOnly BirthDate);

    private readonly IQueryable<Person> _persons = new[]
    {
        new Person(10895, "Jean Martin", new DateOnly(1985, 3, 16)),
        new Person(10944, "António Langa", new DateOnly(1991, 12, 1)),
        new Person(11203, "Julie Smith", new DateOnly(1958, 10, 10)),
        new Person(11205, "Nur Sari", new DateOnly(1922, 4, 27)),
        new Person(11898, "Jose Hernandez", new DateOnly(2011, 5, 3)),
        new Person(12130, "Kenji Sato", new DateOnly(2004, 1, 9)),
    }.AsQueryable();

    private Task PerformSearch() { 
        var url = NavMan.GetUriWithQueryParameter(nameof(SearchString), SearchString);
        NavMan.NavigateTo(url);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }   
}

The output as below:

